# Issue With Parallel Execution - Selenium Grid on AWS

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-grid

I am running a Selenium-Grid using Fargate on AWS and it works great, however when I allow the browser nodes to have more than 1 browser session it causes failures.

I notice that the 2 failures it causes are drop down menus, and timed success messages.

I think because it is switching between active browsers it misses the timed success messages while it is executing commands on another session.

I think with the dropdown it is opening the dropdown, doing something in the other session, and then coming back to choose the selection but the dropdown window is no longer active because it switched browsers and the state of the element is no longer to be open.

What can I do about this? Is there a way to make a block of commands in a test always finish executing before the node is allowed to switch to another session to execute more commands? Do I need to just add retry functionality for the dropdown components and remove the success message checks?